# Probability of measuring state $|+\rangle$ and state $|-\rangle$ given a state and a basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

I am given a basis $|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$ and $|-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)$ and i am given a three qubit state $|\phi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}|1\rangle |0\rangle |1\rangle + \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}|0\rangle |1\rangle |0\rangle $

What is the probability of measuring state $|+\rangle|+\rangle|+\rangle$ and what is the probability of measuring state $|-\rangle|-\rangle|-\rangle$?

I know how to express the state $|0\rangle $ and $|1\rangle $ in the basis above, that would be $|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|+\rangle + |-\rangle)$ and $|1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|+\rangle - |-\rangle)$

but when attempting to do $|\left(\langle+|\langle+|\langle+|\right)|\phi\rangle|^2$ I can't really get anywhere.

How do I solve this?

Comment: What does it mean to measure a three qubit state as $|+\rangle$? Does it mean all three qubits are in the $|+\rangle$ state?

Comment: @BioPhysicist the question seems weird to me as well, I thought about not treating it as qubits but rather as a general quantum state, even then I do not know...

Comment: @BioPhysicist yeah, I really have no idea, why this should have anything to do with qubits, the exercise is so weirdly stated..., let's just treat it as a quantum state

Comment: Still, it doesn't make much sense. It would need to say something like "What is the probability of measuring state $|i\rangle|j\rangle|k\rangle$?" Where $i,j,k$ are each either $+$ or $-$

Comment: @BioPhysicist ah, thank you for that, I mean the states $|+\rangle |+\rangle |+\rangle $ and $ |-\rangle |-\rangle |-\rangle  $

Comment: are you sure it is |1> |0> |1> and not an entangled state?, if it is entangled, you'd have to un-entangle (linear algebra would be fine)

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi there is nothing in the exercise that would say that it is an entangled state, that's why i am a bit struggling :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I don't think your state is normalized and probably what was meant was $$|\phi\rangle = \sqrt{\frac13}|101\rangle + \sqrt{\frac23}|010\rangle.$$(But as written you can also normalize it by multiplying by $\sqrt{3/5}$ and converting the denominator to 5.)

There are several ways to do this problem. Possibly the easiest is to rewrite the state that you are dotting with, $$|{+}{+}{+}\rangle = \sqrt{\frac18} \big(|000\rangle + |001\rangle + \dots + |111\rangle\big),$$ to reveal that $$\langle{+}{+}{+}|\phi\rangle = \sqrt{\frac18}\sqrt{\frac13} + \sqrt{\frac18}\sqrt{\frac23},$$ while $|{-}{-}{-}\rangle,$ having negative signs in front of every term with an odd number of ones, instead generates
$$\langle{-}{-}{-}|\phi\rangle = \sqrt{\frac18}\sqrt{\frac13} - \sqrt{\frac18}\sqrt{\frac23},$$and the probabilities are of course the squares of these amplitudes. So, uh, $\frac18 \pm \frac1{12}\sqrt{2}$ if I am doing the quadratic equation right in my head?

The other way is indeed as the other answer says, to convert the above into the appropriate basis, so each $|1\rangle$ becomes a $|+\rangle - |-\rangle$ and each $|0\rangle$ becomes a $|+\rangle + |-\rangle$ and so we have$$\begin{align}
|\phi\rangle =& \sqrt{\frac1{24}}\big(|{+}{+}{+}\rangle - |{+}{+}{-}\rangle +
|{+}{-}{+}\rangle-|{+}{-}{-}\rangle \\
&\hphantom{\frac1{24}}~~-|{-}{+}{+}\rangle + |{-}{+}{-}\rangle - |{-}{-}{+}\rangle + |{-}{-}{-}\rangle\big)\\
&+\sqrt{\frac1{12}}\big(|{+}{+}{+}\rangle + |{+}{+}{-}\rangle -
|{+}{-}{+}\rangle-|{+}{-}{-}\rangle \\
&\hphantom{+\frac1{12}}~~~~+|{-}{+}{+}\rangle + |{-}{+}{-}\rangle - |{-}{-}{+}\rangle - |{-}{-}{-}\rangle\big),\\
\end{align}$$
from which you can read not just those amplitudes but diverse other ones that you might be interested in in the Hadamard basis. Note that there is really no “hard work” here in either case, it is all mostly just keeping track of signs of terms. This is one reason why the Hadamard basis is so nice to think about problems with.

Comment: ah, so I just needed to convert to the given basis and then compare the amplitude coefficients, thank You very much

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Notice that $\vert 0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vert +\rangle + \vert - \rangle)$ and $\vert 1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vert +\rangle - \vert - \rangle)$.

Step 2: Expand $\vert\phi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\vert 1\rangle \vert0\rangle \vert1\rangle + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt 3}\vert0\rangle \vert1\rangle \vert0\rangle$ using the substitution in Step 1.

Step 3: The squares of the coefficients in your expansion in Step 2 should add to 1. The squares of the coefficients of the $\vert +\rangle\vert +\rangle\vert +\rangle$ and $\vert -\rangle\vert -\rangle\vert -\rangle$ states are the probabilities you desire.

The statement below is incorrect. $\vert 0\rangle$ and $\vert 1\rangle$ are as written above, not as you have written them.

> I know how to express the state $|\phi\rangle $ in the basis above,
> that would be $|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|+\rangle + |-\rangle)$
> and $|1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|+\rangle - |-\rangle)$